# bot command hide members

Tags: hide, telegram-bot, member

I created a private group and would like to hide the names of the members (as in the channels). The only ones who can see the members are the group administrators.
I created a bot with BotFather and I do not know how to set this command to hide members. Does anyone help me? I'm not practical bot programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to hide members in Telegram Groups, What is the reason you want to hide them?

Comment: The group I created is a group where many people do not know each other and I do not want to know the names of the members and the mobile number. Members can join the group with a QRCode that contains links to the group. I could create a channel but in this case nobody could send messages.